# AcroRd32.exe Maxes Out Core

Tags: cpu-usage

My CPU usage hit 100%.  `Process Explorer` shows two instances of AcroRd32.exe.  Each one is maxing out 1 core.  But, there is no Adobe/Acrobat Reader window showing.  I had closed the windows earlier.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: I would suggest trying other PDF readers than Adobe's Reader. Chrome/Firefox/SumatraPDF/Foxit are some alternatives you could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acrord32.exe is normally associated with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

If you have not run it yourself (by opening a PDF document) then it may be running from a web browser such as Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome. Do you have a browser open with PDF documents open?

Otherwise it could be that Adobe Reader is corrupted in which case you can try uninstalling the current version and re-downloading it [from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/reader.html).

As a last resort it is potentially possible that it is a virus masquerading as Adobe Reader, try following the advice in [this quesion](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) regarding virus scanning and generally cleaning the computer.

Comment: I find that the older versions of acrobat regularly crash but leave a process running in the background this way. Usually the first I hear is when a user can't open any pdfs

Answer (score 0):

It may be a virus program named "acrord32.exe", a familiar name for running without looking dubious.

In Process Explorer, right click on it, then see properties, and see the path: is the *real* Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score -1):

Allow me to convey my own work in this regard.

Another way through the closing process of loading system. There is then no need for any changes to the registry, parameters or settings Acrobat Reader. Batch script prepared by default closes Acrord32.exe process and to this end has been designed, but the script can be used to close as any other process too burdensome system, which was suspended when the script calls to the appropriate parameter. If this parameter contains a long name with a space, you must enclose the parameter in quotation marks. Inside the script, to the beginning of the several parameters can be determined, for example. Time of suspension, the time of re-checking, or where the report is to be created (LOG). The script closes all processes meet the criteria for any user, of course, not the system that can not be closed. Can be useful on the server, the work of many users.  The script is optimized in order to minimize itself burdened processor.

Copy the following text and save as a file Batch (extension .BAT) with any filename that You want.

```
@echo off
REM Automatic closing Acrobat Reader or other process parameter specified in the call, which too much high the CPU
REM Preparing:  Artur Zgadzaj
REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET REPEAT_TIME_VERIFICATION_[seconds]=7
SET IDLE_TIME_[seconds]=5

SET LOG_FOLDER=C:\UTIL\LOG

REM    # # # #      CHECKING OR IS STARTED AS ADMINISTRATOR     # # # # #

FSUTIL | findstr /I "volume" > nul&if not errorlevel 1  goto Administrator_OK

cls
echo ************************************
echo ***    RUN  AS  ADMINISTRATOR    ***
echo ************************************
echo.
echo.
echo Call up just as the Administrator. Abbreviation can be done to the script and set:
echo.
echo      Shortcut ^> Advanced ^> Run as Administrator
echo.
echo.
echo Alternatively, a single run "Run as Administrator"
echo or in the Schedule tasks with highest privileges
pause > nul
goto:eof
:Administrator_OK

SET WD=day
if "%~1"==""  (SET Close_Process=AcroRd32.exe)  else  (SET "Close_Process=%~1")
MD %LOG_FOLDER% 2>NUL
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:again
cls
echo Automatic closing %Close_Process%, which are charged to the processor too ...&echo.&echo.

FOR /F "tokens=2,7,8 delims=,"  %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /v /FO CSV^|find /I ^"%Close_Process%^"') DO (

  SET PROC=%%C
  SET PROC=!PROC:"=!

  FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=:"  %%s IN ("!PROC!") DO (SET PR=%%t
      if "!PR:~0,1!"=="0"  (SET /A PROC_TIME=%%s*60+!PR:~1,1!)  else  (SET /A PROC_TIME=%%s*60+!PR:~0,2!))

  if !PROC_TIME! GTR %IDLE_TIME_[seconds]%   (
      SET PID=%%A
      SET PID=!PID:"=!

      %SystemRoot%\system32\taskkill.exe /PID !PID! /F

      SET B=%%B
      SET B=!B:%USERDOMAIN%\=!
      SET B=!B:%COMPUTERNAME%\=!
      SET Process_User=!B:"=!

      if not "!DATE_WD!"=="%DATE%" ((FOR /F "tokens=1" %%W IN ('POWERSHELL GET-DATE -format dddd') DO SET WD=%%W)&&SET DATE_WD=%DATE%)
      echo %TIME:~0,8%    ^(Hanging:  !PROC:~-5!^)         !Process_User! >>"%LOG_FOLDER%\%DATE:-=.%  ^(!WD:~0,3!^)  Close_%Close_Process%.TXT"
      )
  )

TIMEOUT /T %REPEAT_TIME_VERIFICATION_[seconds]% > nul
goto again
```